# Why use a voltage reference chip rather than a known VCC and resistor?

Tags: comparator, voltage-reference

To elaborate, I'm making a circuit that converts an analogue sensor output into an on/off state using a comparator.

Is there any reason that I should use a voltage reference chip as the low comparison rather than the **VCC** put through a resistor, given that my **VCC** is known as long as the circuit is running?

**Edit:**
Here's a schematic of my reverse-biased photodiode sensor. The output line is the one that goes left offscreen near the bottom.

The sensor is relative to VCC, but its output changes A LOT with fluctuations to VCC, so fluctuations in VCC can be quite significant.

It's for a brightness sensor: I basically want a digital switch to say "Is it dark or bright?" so anything within the range of a few decimals of a volt is good.

[image]

Comment: How accurate does the threshold for the comparator need to be? A reference created from VCC and a resistor divider could have more variation due to resistor tolerance / temperature co-efficient and noise on VCC, compared to a dedicated voltage reference chip. I.e. it depends on the application requirements about which to use.

Comment: Do you want to compare to a known voltage or to a fraction of VCC? Does the output of the analogue sensor at the threshold you want to detect depend on VCC?

Comment: @ChesterGillon Doesn't need to be that accurate. It's for a brightness sensor, I basically want a digital switch to say "Is it dark or bright?" so anything within the range of a few decimals of a volt is good.

Comment: @AndrewMorton My VCC is a known voltage, or atleast very close to a known voltage.

Comment: Are both the reference and sensor using thr same supply? If so, doesn't the VCC cancel out?

Comment: @Justme What do you mean?

Comment: @SteamRanger For example, if both the comparator input and sensor output are both relative to VCC, it is irrelevant what the VCC is and how stable it is. If sensor outputs 50% of VCC, comparator will have 50% of VCC too. So what is the sensor and how you connect it to comparator?

Comment: To elaborate on @Justme, is your sensor's output *ratiometric* to the sensor's excitation voltage?  If so, then there are few downsides to using Vcc with a simple voltage divider as your comparator's reference voltage.

Comment: State the analog sensor in question. A part number would be useful so we can tell you what you should do.

Comment: @Justme Ah yes, I see what you mean. Yes the sensor is relative to VCC, but its output changes A LOT with fluctuations to VCC, so fluctuations in VCC can be quite significant.

Comment: @MOSFET It's a reverse biased photodiode sensor.

Comment: @SteamRanger That's weird. A reversed-biased photodiode current is independent of the voltage bias. Are you describing this properly?

Comment: @SteamRanger To help get a better answer can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/707840/edit) the question to include a schematic showing how the ``reverse biased photodiode sensor`` is intended to be connected, and also a link to the datasheet for the sensor.

Comment: @SteamRanger You should post the rest of the circuit. What you have is not very useful and most of us would assume what you described would be at least what you depicted.

Comment: @SteamRanger Have you considered that the not-so-fast response time of a photoresistor might be an advantage? For example, you might not want the circuit to respond much to a very brief illumination change. What needs to know if it's light or dark?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume you mean voltage divider derived reference rather than "Vcc and resistor" from here on out because VCC and a resistor alone won't establish a reference at all without a known, fixed current sink.

The short answer is: the precision voltage reference is an absolute reference and the voltage divider is a relative reference (to VCC).

In a comparator arrangement, there are implications for using one or the other that exclusively depend on the sensor. Let's look at the 2 circuits for reference:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqFuTL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some sensors intrinsically have an absolute reference, for example, a reversed-biased photodiode generates a photocurrent based on incident light received at the PN junction. This will be the same current independent of VCC, which means the voltage (signal) dropped across the resistor will be the same, therefore, it falls into the category of "absolute" sensors. Other sensors have internal bandgap references baked right into the sensing element. Some accelerometers and temperature sensors do that. The LM35 temperature sensor has it's own internal reference and puts out 10mV/degC independent of supply voltage. In this case, an absolute voltage reference would be required for the comparator, otherwise, changes in VCC will modify the comparator sensing threshold.

On the other hand, some sensors have ratiometric outputs. The most common are resistor divider bridge sensors. The most common would be a resistor in series with a photocell or thermistor. In this case, notice how the output signal not only depends on the physical quantity being measured but also the VCC supply rail. We say the signal "tracks" the rail, meaning if VCC goes up, so does the signal by a scaled (ratio) amount. This is not inherently a problem if the comparator reference tracks the same changes to VCC and that's exactly how this kind of circuit works. From a detection standpoint, the absolute signal doesn't matter as long as it's correct relative to the reference (which is also tracking the changes in VCC). A more exotic example would be those galvanically-isolated hall-based current sensors from Alegro Microdevices that put out a scaled (ratio) of mV/A detected. The absolute signal changes with VCC but the ratio of signal with respect to VCC is constant.

Comment: A reverse biased photodiode produces different currents when VCC changes, as VCC changes it's capacitance.

Comment: Side note, if I need to get a very specific voltage, how do I get that, considering most reference chips have mV precision? Would I need to use a voltage divider then or is there some other solution?

Comment: @SteamRanger No. The photodiode does not produce different photocurrents with different VCC levels. Sure, there will be some leakage current, but that should be negligible with respect to the signal levels you are sampling. Yes, the capacitance goes down with a stronger bias hence improving HF performance but that doesn't change the photocurrent. Some voltage references are adjustable so you can get any voltage you want. As for precision, you have to buy the best you need. If that's still not good enough, compromises need to be made or a non-trivial solution needs to be developed.