# What's the best way to make sure I have a known VCC on a battery powered device?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, low-power, battery-operated, ldo

I'm making a portable device (well not really portable, but intended to be set up away from mains power) powered by AA batteries. I need a stable **VCC** as I have displays that I don't want the brightness to change on (I'm also considering using **VCC** as a reference, see [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/707840/why-use-a-voltage-reference-chip-rather-than-a-known-vcc-and-resistor)). I need the **VCC** to remain stable as the batteries drain, atleast to a certain extent (say until the batteries are atleast 80% depleted).

I'm thinking I'll use LDO(s) to provide power, as none of the circuits should consume that much power so I won't need anything more bulky. Is there any better solution for this kind of device, or is it fine to use LDO(s)?

Comment: We don't know anything about what you are powering, but almost anything is better than linear regulators. The best solution depends on what voltages you have on inputs and outputs and what currents you need. Maybe there is also better solution than AA batteries?

Comment: Basically all I'm powering is some IR LEDs, some 7-segment displays and some logic chips. The total power consumption is 2A tops.

Comment: 2A sounds a lot for a bit of logic and some LEDs, but if that is an accurate assessment, you'll almost definitely want a switch-mode power supply. The kind of which depends on the actual voltages and batteries involved. Please answer *all* the questions Justme asked!

Comment: @Justme I don't really know if anything but AA batteries is suitable, as it must be battery powered, it must be compact, and it must be able to be stored in a hot place for a long time without checks. The input voltage so to say is 1.5V, going down to about 1.1V where I stop caring about getting energy out of the battery. In terms of outputs, I need to produce a 5V VCC with noise less than 100mV either direction, and as said around 2A peak current.

Comment: @SteamRanger the requirements you list (high energy density, long storage live, maintenance free) all say that AA are *not* the right choice. If your output voltage is higher than your battery voltage, then linear regulators are simply impossible to use, as they can only reduce, not increase voltage, so that settles that. 100 mV is not a complicated requirement to achieve.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've marked a post as the answer. I've had a look at switching regulators and they seem fine. Also, high energy density is not one of my requirements, it's fine if the circuit only runs for a few hours before it needs batteries replaced, and the setup of AAs I've got gives 4A/h. How are AAs not long storage life?   They last a few years on the shelf, and even then they're expended quickly in the device so needing to replace them would be taken for granted.

Comment: @SteamRanger "It must be compact"==high energy density, literally, or you're wasting space for a battery that could be more compact for the same runtime. AA cells (typically alcaline or zinc-carbon batteries) have relatively high self-discharge, so they are not able to be stored for long; after a few years on the shelf, the energy they still store has dropped significantly. That's the reason that you need to exchange the alkaline batteries in cheap smoke detectors every couple of years, but if you spend a bit more, you get a smoke detector with a lithium battery that will last 10 years or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you have the choice between switching regulators and linear regulators with LDOs being just a flavor of linear regulators.

If efficiency is a concern, you maybe want to use a switching regulator. Also switching regulators usually cover a wider input voltage range than linear regulators. With the right topology, the input voltage can even drop below Vcc.

Linear regulators on the other hand are usually simpler to use and less noisy. But the input voltage always needs to be above Vcc. LDOs can have their input a little closer to Vcc than conventional linear regulators. But LDOs can also have a tendency to become unstable under certain circumstances.

Considering your circuit is drawing 2 A and you need Vcc stable "until the batteries are at least 80% depleted" a switching regulator appears to be the more favorable option.

If you used a linear regulator, the input voltage just being 1 V above Vcc would cause 2 Watts of power dissipation inside the regulator at 2 A. That would heat up the linear regulator quite a bit.

Comment: I was unaware of the existence of switching regulators (I'm a bit new to electronics incase you can't tell), thanks, they suit my needs well. I found one with 150mV noise, which is just fine.